# Login Button is not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

I am working on my app and I am using `UserDefaults` to store value of token

```
   @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("driver/login"), method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any]? else{ return}
            guard let userData = json["data"] as! [String: AnyObject]? else{ return}
            guard let token = userData["token"] as! String? else { return}
            print("The value of token is \(token)")
            let user = UserModel(with: userData)
            print("The value of \(user)")
            UserDefaults.standard.setAccessToken(token)
            let userArchiveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:user )
            UserDefaults.standard.setUserData(userArchiveData as AnyObject)
            let nav = UIStoryboard.main.instantiate(.mainNavigation) as! UINavigationController
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiate(.homeVC) as! HomeViewController
             nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            showNormalAlertWithTitle("Invalid Email", message: "Please Provide correct email and password")
            break

        }
    }
    }
```

Here I am storing the token value when `login button` is clicked. When I click the logout option it opens the `login view controller`, this is the code I wrote in logout function

```
 func logOut() {
    UserDefaults.standard.setUserData(nil)
    UserDefaults.standard.setAccessToken(nil)
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNavigation")
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Now the problem is, after logout when I am going to click `login button` again, the `login button` is not working, It is not pushing to the `HomeViewController`

The code I wrote in `AppDelegate` class:

```
 func goToRootViewController() {
    storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let nav = UIStoryboard.main.instantiate(.mainNavigation) as! UINavigationController
    if UserDefaults.standard.getAccessToken().isEmpty {
        gotoLogin()
        return
    } else {
        let homeVc = UIStoryboard.main.instantiate(.homeVC) as! HomeViewController
        nav.pushViewController(homeVc, animated: false)
    }
    let leftMenuVC = storyBoard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuVC") as! MenuViewController
    container = MFSideMenuContainerViewController.container(withCenter: nav, leftMenuViewController: leftMenuVC, rightMenuViewController: nil)
    container?.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNone
    window?.rootViewController = container
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: did you add `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`  after set `UserDefaults.standard.setUserData(nil)
    UserDefaults.standard.setAccessToken(nil)` at Logout function

Comment: Yes I used it now but not working I use breakpoint to see method is working or not but everything is working

Comment: Are you able to catch the program flow using breakpoint in button action method?

Comment: Yes I am all the methods are working fine when I used breakpoint it is calling the method to go to homescreen

Comment: @V_rohit Did you try to get the value of `UserDefaults.standard.getAccessToken()` when you debug

Comment: Yes....... I did that, it storing the token value because when i run the code again it opens the homescreen

Comment: what does he `getAccessToken()` return? `String` or `String?`

Comment: it returns Sting

Comment: Have you tried `synchronize()` in the `setAccessToken`? Not after it, but in the function itself.

Comment: why we need to use in setAccessToken

Comment: to make sure that the data is synchronized after setting it.

Comment: yes I am using it but I don't understand why it is not going to the nextViewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168537/discussion-between-hardik-parmar-and-v-rohit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the rooViewController in logout. So when you push homecontroller again, it is actually pushing the controller but the navigation controller is not the rootViewController now. So you will have to do this in success part:

```
let nav = UIStoryboard.main.instantiate(.mainNavigation) as! UINavigationController
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiate(.homeVC) as! HomeViewController
nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```